# Flash Player "data" update working in FF, but not x-browser (twitch)

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, object, cross-browser

I'm getting streams from Twitch and dynamically updating the stream information via jQuery.
It works in Firefox but not Chrome / IE.

Javascript:

```
$(function() { 
    var streamer = $("#stream-list ul li.active").first().attr("id");
    $("#live_embed_player_flash").attr("data", "http://sv.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf?channel=" + streamer);
    $("#flashvars").val("hostname=sv.twitch.tv&channel=" + streamer + "&auto_play=true&start_volume=0");

    $("#stream-list ul li").click(function(){
        $("#stream-list ul li.active").first().removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        var streamer = $(this).attr("id");
        $("#live_embed_player_flash").attr("data", "http://sv.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf?channel=" + streamer);
        $("#flashvars").val("hostname=sv.twitch.tv&channel=" + streamer + "&auto_play=true&start_volume=25");
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
   <li class="active" id="name-of-stream"></li>
   <li></li>
   <li></li>
</ul>

 <div id="player">
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" height="480" width="720" id="live_embed_player_flash" data="" bgcolor="#000000">
        <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
        <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
        <param name="allowNetworking" value="all" />
        <param name="movie" value="http://sv.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf" />
        <param name="flashvars" value="" />
    </object>
</div>
```

If you want a link for the example, [follow this link (http://icguides.com/)!](http://icguides.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it with jQuery SWFobject

http://jquery.thewikies.com/swfobject/

Will post the code here in case someone finds this question and need an answer.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/swfobject.jquery.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" >
     $(function() { 
            var streamer = $("#stream-list ul li.active").first().attr("id");
            $('#player').flash({
                    swf: 'http://sv.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf?channel=' + streamer,
                    width: 720,
                    height: 480,
                    flashvars: {
                        hostname: 'sv.twitch.tv',
                        channel: streamer,
                        auto_play: 'true',
                        start_volume: '0'
                    }
                });

   

    $("#stream-list ul li").click(function(){
        $("#stream-list ul li.active").first().removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        var streamer = $(this).attr("id");
        $('#player').flash({
                swf: 'http://sv.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf?channel=' + streamer,
                width: 720,
                height: 480,
                    flashvars: {
                        channel: streamer,
                        start_volume: '25'
                    }
                });
    });
});     
</script>
```

And all the HTML needed is:

> ```
>    <div id="stream-list">
>        <ul>
>            <li class="active" id="streamer-name"></li>
>            <li></li>
>        </ul>
>    </div>
>
>    <div id="player">
>
>    </div>
> ```